# How to get the return type of a function of an already deployed contract?

Tags: solidity, tokens, remix

I am currently working on a real estate blockchain project. Now I have 2 contracts `user.sol` and `property.sol`. The person who is registered on the website through `user.sol` can only buy or sell property in `property.sol`. I have a modifier in `user.sol` contract named `CheckingRegistration` which checks the person who is requesting to buy or sell property in `property.sol` is registered or not. I have deployed my user contract on blockchain. Now my question is how do I access the state of a person that whether he is registered or not in my `property.sol` which will deploy later.

Comment: Please share your code. It is hard to refer to your question otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Instance of user to the property contract like this:

```
contract User{
    function CheckingRegistration...        
}
contract Property{
    User us;
}
```

Then u have to write a function where the User in Property is given to the deployed User address like:

```
function Property(address _a}...{
         us = User(_a)
}
```

After that u can call the CheckingRegistration Function for the specific User.

Cheers